# BO 4.0 issue : SDK Version 1400 does not support Crystal Enterprise version 1261

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects-sdk

Hi While using running sample java code for displaying list of reports in BO universe i am getting following error message :

```
Connecting...
com.crystaldecisions.sdk.exception.SDKException$UnsupportedEnterpriseVersion: SDK Version 1400  does not support Crystal Enterprise version 1261  (FWM 02032)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.LogonService.checkVersionCompatibility(LogonService.java:737)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.LogonService.doLogon(LogonService.java:1067)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.LogonService.doUserLogon(LogonService.java:884)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.LogonService.doUserLogon(LogonService.java:815)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.LogonService.userLogon(LogonService.java:211)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.occa.security.internal.SecurityMgr.userLogon(SecurityMgr.java:177)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.SessionMgr.logon_aroundBody0(SessionMgr.java:454)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.SessionMgr.logon_aroundBody1$advice(SessionMgr.java:512)
    at com.crystaldecisions.sdk.framework.internal.SessionMgr.logon(SessionMgr.java:1)
    at boxi.Program.main(Program.java:23)
Finished!
```

Any idea why this error is coming ?

Answer (score 2):

It appears that you are using the BI4.0 SDK to connect to a CMS that is an older version (apparently XI3).  You should be using the XI3 jars instead.